# Type is not callable _isExcludedFromFee[(owner)] = true;

Tags: typeerror, solidity, callable, remix, owner

My token contract with solidity 0.8.4 is catching:

```
TypeError: Type is not callable 

_isExcludedFromFee[(owner)] = true;
^^^^^^^^
```

From:

```
     constructor ()  {
        _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;
        
        IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F);
         // Create a uniswap pair for this new token
        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory())
            .createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());

        // set the rest of the contract variables
        uniswapV2Router = _uniswapV2Router;
        
        _isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;
        
        emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _tTotal);
        
        initialize();
        pause();
    }
```

I believe it is "owner" that is causing the error, and will attach the Ownable and token contract below. There is an owner function that is typically included SafeMoon's Ownable that returns _owner but that just breaks everything more since I have newly declared address public owner.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to correct by making these changes:

```
    contract Ownable is Context {
    
 // OWNER DATA
    address public _owner;
    address public _proposedOwner;
    address private _oldOwner;
    uint256 private _lockTime;
    
    // OWNABLE EVENTS
    event OwnershipTransferProposed(
        address indexed currentOwner,
        address indexed proposedOwner
    );
    event OwnershipTransferDisregarded(
        address indexed oldProposedOwner
    );
    event OwnershipTransferred(
        address indexed oldOwner,
        address indexed newOwner
    );
    
 
    
     /**
     * @dev Initializes the contract setting the deployer as the initial owner.
     */
    constructor () {
        address msgSender = _msgSender();
        _owner = msgSender;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), msgSender);
    }
    
   /**
     * @dev Returns the address of the current owner.
     */
    function owner() public view returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }
    
/**
     * @dev Returns the address of the current owner.
     */
    
    /**
     * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
     */
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(_owner == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
        _;
    }

     /**
     * @dev Leaves the contract without owner. It will not be possible to call
     * `onlyOwner` functions anymore. Can only be called by the current owner.
     *
     * NOTE: Renouncing ownership will leave the contract without an owner,
     * thereby removing any functionality that is only available to the owner.
     */
    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
        _owner = address(0);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfers ownership of the contract to a new account (`newOwner`).
     * Can only be called by the current owner.
     */
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, newOwner);
        _owner = newOwner;
    }

    function getUnlockTime() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _lockTime;
    }

    //Locks the contract for owner for the amount of time provided
    function lock(uint256 time) public virtual onlyOwner {
        _oldOwner = _owner;
        _owner = address(0);
        _lockTime = block.timestamp + time;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
    }
    
    //Unlocks the contract for owner when _lockTime is exceeds
    function unlock() public virtual {
        require(_oldOwner == msg.sender, "You don't have permission to unlock");
        require(block.timestamp > _lockTime , "Contract is locked until 7 days");
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, _oldOwner);
        _owner = _oldOwner;
    }

  }
```